# get element size during window resize fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have some code to get the size of the body on screen during a window resize event and use this elsewhere, however for some reason the size that is determined is always the size before the resizing:

```
$(document).on('ready', function () {
    initResize();
});

function initResize() {
    $(window).on('resize', doResize).trigger('resize');
};

function doResize() {
    var wh = $('.game').height();
    var ww = $('.game').width();
    console.log("game " + ww +"x" +wh);
}
```

and the console output always returns the same data, yet if I change the selector to $(window) it changes as the window resizes.  Can someone help please?

the html is very simple:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/myStyle.css"  /
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/init.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<section class="game">
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

and the css:

```
@charset "utf-8";


* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}

html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Is '#myelement' actually resizing?

Comment: Please add Html code and you are missing ) in on('ready',func(){});

Comment: @Elias, I have expanded the description, the element in question is the body in this case, I have noticed that when rendered the body is shown in the dev tools of chrome as having a definition of `<body style="zoom: 1; height: 613px; width: 1920px;">`

Comment: [Not reproduceable](http://jsfiddle.net/emedv63a/1/) in FF using the provided code. But if you have a static size of `body`, `section` will use the same `width` too, hence no change happens.

Comment: Apologies to all, I simplified the problem here and missed a line of code in the doResize that overrode everything else, `$('body').css({'height':wh+'px','width':ww+'px'});` this is now removed and all works.